# How to create a specific sorting function in jQuery Tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using this great version of jQuery Tablesorter: http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html

Everything is working well but now I have this problem: in my table, I have one column which contains positions of basketball players. Therefore I want that column to be sorted logically like this: PG-SG-SF-PF-C.

I tried to create this custom sorting function - look at my script, column 2:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(".stats").tablesorter({
            sortInitialOrder: 'desc',
            sortRestart: true,
            // Enable use of the characterEquivalents reference 
            sortLocaleCompare: false, 
            // if false, upper case sorts BEFORE lower case 
            ignoreCase: true,
            headers: { 
                0: { 
                        sortInitialOrder: 'asc'
                }, 
                1: { 
                        sortInitialOrder: 'asc'
                },
                2: { 
                        textSorter: function(a, b){ 
                            var positions = {
                                "PG": 0,
                                "SG": 10,
                                "SF": 20,
                                "PF": 30,
                                "C": 40
                            };
                            return ((positions[a] < positions[b]) ? -1 : ((positions[a] > positions[b]) ? 1 : 0)); 
                        },
                        sortInitialOrder: 'asc'
                }
            }
        }
    ); 

});
```

However, the column is still being sorted alphabetically like a normal text string (C-PF-PG-SF-SG).

Where am I making a mistake? I am not particularly strong in Javascript so it is probably somewhere in the sorting function. Thank you.

Comment: Use console.log to confirm it is getting into the `textSorter` function first, then if it is, inspect the values of `a` and `b`.

Comment: It seems that it never gets into the sorting function because nothing is showing in Firebug after I added console.log("We are here"); into the function. I don't understand how this is possible, I thought it has to go into the function once I click on the heading of column 2 (actually the third column in the table).

Comment: Then the problem becomes, why is it ignoring the textSorter option that you passed into said column.

Comment: The example here shows an entirely different way of using it... http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-custom-sort.html

Comment: I am unable to figure it out. I tried to add table, column as arguments to the function but it doesn't help. I want the sorting function to work this way regardless of the sortLocaleCompare configuration, therefore I am not using the line with if (table.config.sortLocaleCompare).

Comment: No what i'm saying is it may not be a valid argument for the headers object. I don't see it used that way anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. I had to place the entire textSorter: ... up on the same level as sortRestart etc. So now the problem is that I need the function to apply only on one specific column, not to change text sorting in the entire table.

Comment: It has a column argument, what does it contain?

Comment: After clicling on the heading of column 2, it contains 2. And column 2 is sorting correctly as it is supposed to. But now sorting of column 1 which contains player names is not working well (it sorts after first click but doesn't do anything after any subsequent clicks).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out by adding my own parser like it is shown in this question: [Sorting Image and hyperlink columns in a table using JQuery Sorter plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014892/sorting-image-and-hyperlink-columns-in-a-table-using-jquery-sorter-plugin)

I will copy my script that works as I want it to work, hope it helps someone:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
            // set a unique id 
            id: 'positions',
            is: function(s) {
                    // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
                    return false;
            },
            format: function(s) {
                    // format your data for normalization 
                    return s.toLowerCase()
                            .replace("pg", "d")
                            .replace("sg", "h")
                            .replace("sf", "m")
                            .replace("pf", "r")
                            .replace("c", "v");
            },
            // set type, either numeric or text 
            type: 'text'
    });     

    $(".stats").tablesorter({
            sortInitialOrder: 'desc',
            sortRestart: true,
            headers: { 
                0: { 
                        sortInitialOrder: 'asc'
                }, 
                1: { 
                        sortInitialOrder: 'asc'
                },
                2: { 
                        sorter: 'positions',
                        sortInitialOrder: 'asc'
                }
            }
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: This really helped me in solving my issue with custom sorting

Comment: helpful for me too. Thanks. noted that first column is index 0

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thanks. It really helped out.

Comment: I'm glad that it's still useful :)

Comment: It's 2024 and still useful!