# jQuery Tablesorter custom sort not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the jQuery-based [Tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) library in a Django-based website. I'm trying to get the "Pos" column in my table to sort according to a custom order which I am setting in the Parser function. I've tried following several articles (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238795/how-to-create-a-specific-sorting-function-in-jquery-tablesorter) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014892/sorting-image-and-hyperlink-columns-in-a-table-using-jquery-sorter-plugin)) but it still sorts alphabetically only.

The way it behaves...

- On page load, clicking the Pos column does not change the order but it does cycle through the little up/down icon
- Sorting by the Name column (which works), *then* clicking on Pos sets it back to how it was sorted on page load

**JS**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Disable sorting on specified columns
    $("#fullTable thead th:eq(3)").data("sorter", false); //Monday
    $("#fullTable thead th:eq(4)").data("sorter", false); //Tuesday
    $("#fullTable thead th:eq(5)").data("sorter", false); //Wednesday
    $("#fullTable thead th:eq(6)").data("sorter", false); //you get the idea...
    $("#fullTable thead th:eq(7)").data("sorter", false);
    $("#fullTable thead th:eq(8)").data("sorter", false);
    $("#fullTable thead th:eq(9)").data("sorter", false);
    $("#fullTable thead th:eq(10)").data("sorter", false); //Sunday

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
      // set a unique id
      id: 'positions',
      is: function(s) {
          // return false so this parser is not auto detected
          return false;
      },
      format: function(s) {
          // format your data for normalization
          return s.toLowerCase()
              .replace(/A/, 0)
              .replace(/E2/, 1)
              .replace(/E1/, 2)
              .replace(/C2/, 3)
              .replace(/C1/, 4)
              .replace(/SC/, 5)
              .replace(/PC/, 6)
              .replace(/AD/, 7);
      },
      // set type, either numeric or text
      type: 'numeric'
    });

    $("#fullTable").tablesorter({
      cancelSelection: true,
      sortReset: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainTableContainer" style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; width:fit-content; width:-moz-fit-content; height:auto; display:inline-block;">
      <table id='fullTable' class="newtable tablesorter" border="1" alt="Staff Entry table" > <!--PABSO-278-->
        <thead style="border: 1px solid black">
          <tr>
            <th><div style="width:100px">Week</div></th>
            <th><div style="width:200px">Name</div></th>
            <th class="sorter-positions"><div style="width:50px">Pos</div></th>
            <th><div style="width:200px">Monday</div></th>
            <th><div style="width:200px">Tuesday</div></th>
            <th><div style="width:200px">Wednesday</div></th>
            <th><div style="width:200px">Thursday</div></th>
            <th><div style="width:200px">Friday</div></th>
            <th><div style="width:200px">Saturday</div></th>
            <th><div style="width:200px">Sunday</div></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please share an example of the "Pos" data; is it a single letter with or without a number or multiple letters?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make that clear. The Pos data is exactly as in the format section i.e. A, E2, E1, C2, C1, SC, PC, AD. "A" should be ranked lowest (hence it gets replaced with 0) and "AD" should be ranked highest (hence it is replaced with 7).

Answer (score 1):

It was a foolish error of mine that a colleague pointed out:

```
format: function(s) {
      // format your data for normalization
      return s.toLowerCase()
          .replace(/A/, 0)
          .replace(/E2/, 1)
          .replace(/E1/, 2)
          .replace(/C2/, 3)
          .replace(/C1/, 4)
          .replace(/SC/, 5)
          .replace(/PC/, 6)
          .replace(/AD/, 7);
  },
```

I am parsing my table data .toLowerCase(). Therefore when the .replace() calls are made looking for uppercase values, none are found!

Comment: Also, move the `/A/` replace *after the `/AD/` otherwise all of the "AD" entries will sort with "A"